# how to make the proper if-statement for memory game

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am doing a memory game for a school project and i am having a hard time with the javascript... I need to make an if statement that compares the cards and then if they match up, then you get a score and if not then they turn around again. and i have no idea how to do it. (the console log's are just to see if the code was working)

vanilla javascript only :)

codepen:

https://codepen.io/anna100d/pen/wvgQLdW

```js
//Function for the dropdown content
function dropdownTips() {
    document.getElementById("mydropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}


window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowncontent");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
             if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
             openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
});

//the game
let score = 0;

const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");


for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
        cards[i].classList.add("open"); 
        console.log(this.id)
        
        if (document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('type') === document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('type')  ) {
            console.log("hello");
        } else {
            console.log("byebye");
        }
        });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color:#00005e;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17%;
  left: 39%;
  right: 40%;
  width: 355px;
}

/*The 'tips?' button and the drop down content*/
header button {
display: inline-flex;
position:absolute;
align-items: center;
right: 2%;
top: 15%;
bottom: 15%;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color:white;
color: #00005e;
border-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
border-color: transparent;
}

header button:hover {
opacity: 80%;
}


.dropdowncontent {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0%;
top: 100%;
background-color:#00005e;
min-width: 160px;
max-width: 400px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
z-index: 100;

}

.dropdowncontent li {
color: white;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.advise{
font-size: 19px;
}

.passwordtips {
font-size: 30px;
left: 20%;
}

.show {
display:block;
}

/*The link in the dropdowncontent*/
a {
text-decoration: underline;
color: white;
}

a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

/*The score counter*/
.score {
  color: #01016e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

/*The game section*/
section {
  max-width: 1300px;
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: #00005e;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

/*The sections content*/
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 185px;
margin-top: 7px;
}

.card{
background-color: #01016e;
color: white;
margin: 10px 10px;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.card h2{
  padding: 2px;
  transform: scale(-1,1);
}

.card:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.open{
animation: flip .5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes flip {
from { 
  background: #00005e;
  font-size: 0;
}
to{
  background: rgb(20, 73, 185);
  font-size:17px;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
}

/* .welcome {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
color: #3c3b6e;
margin-top: 100px;
font-size: 50px;
clear: both;
position: absolute;
}

.startbutton {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-self: center;
margin-top: 100px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #00005e;
color: #e8ebf1;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 4px;
z-index: 0;
border-color: transparent;
}

.startbutton:hover{
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #3c3b6e;
}
*/

/*The game*/


/*The 'DID YOU KNOW' over the ticker*/
.facts {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
margin-top: 30px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #00005e;
}

/*The facts ticker*/
.tcontainer {
max-width: 1200px;
margin-top: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1000;
}

.ticker-wrap {
width: 100%;
padding-left: 100%; 
background-color: #00005e;
}

@keyframes ticker {
0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
100% { transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
}
.ticker-move {
 display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
padding-right: 100%;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: ticker;
animation-duration: 55s;
}
.ticker-move:hover{
animation-play-state: paused; 
}

.ticker-item{
display: inline-block; 
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-right: 3em;
color: white;
min-height: 40px;
font-size: 25px;
}


/*The pause button for the ticker*/
.pause {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.pausebutton {
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #00005e;
color: white;
border-style: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.pausebutton:hover {
background-color: #3c3b6e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>The Password Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>THE PASSWORD GAME</h1>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropdownTips()" class="dropbtn">TIPS?</button>
            <div class="dropdowncontent" id="mydropdown" >
                <ul>
                    <li class="passwordtips">Tips for making strong passwords: </li>
                    <li class="advise">1. Use 16 characters or more (use both uppercase and lowercase letters, number and symbols.)</li>
                    <li class="advise">2. Never use the same password twice.</li>
                    <li class="advise">3. Use a password manager.</li>
                    <li class="advise">4. Don't write your passwords down on paper.</li>
                    <li class="advise">5. Don't share your passwords with others.</li>
                    <li class="advise">6. Change your password after a breach.</li>
                    <li class="advise">7. Sign up for data breach notifications. (like <a href="https://haveibeenpwned.com/" target="_blank">haveibeenpwned.com</a>).</li>
                    <li class="advise">8. Check your accounts regularly for any suspicious activity. </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="score"><h2></h2></div>

    <section>
        <div class="wrapper" id="card-deck">
            <div id="cardOne" class="card"  type="1"><h2>What information should you NEVER use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerSix" class="card"  type="6"><h2>1 log in</h2></div>
            <div id="cardThree" class="card"  type="3"><h2>When should you ALWAYS change your password?</h2></div>
            <div id="anserFive" class="card"  type="5"><h2>suspicious activity</h2></div>
            <div id="cardTwo" class="card"  type="2"><h2>Who is it okay to tell your password to?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerFour" class="card" type="4"><h2>16</h2></div>
            <div id="answerThree" class="card" type="3"><h2>After a data breach</h2></div>
            <div id="answerTwo" class="card" type="2"><h2>No one</h2></div>
            <div id="CardSix" class="card" type="6"><h2>For how many log ins is it okay to use the same password?</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFour" class="card" type="4"><h2>How many characters should you AT LEAST use in a password?</h2></div>
            <div id="answerOne" class="card" type="1"><h2>Name and Birthday</h2></div>
            <div id="cardFive" class="card" type="5"><h2>What should you regularly look for in your accounts?</h2></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="facts">
        <h2>DID YOU KNOW?</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tcontainer"><div class="ticker-wrap"><div class="ticker-move">
        <div class="ticker-item">There is a hacker attack every 39 seconds.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">90% of passwords can be cracked in less than 6 hours.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">80% of hacking related breaches are linked to insufficient passwords.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">59% use their name or birthday in their password.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">6.850.000 passwords are getting hacked each day.</div>
      </div></div></div>

    <div class="pause">
        <p>Hold your mouse over to pause</p>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript/javascript.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your cards all look different tho :P

Comment: Yes it's because its not a proper memory game, just a game in that setting if you know what i mean.

Comment: It is a nice idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a custom attribute like [data-card](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) and set it equal to two elements in your HTML

```
<div class="myCard" data-card="firstSet"></div>
<div class="myCard" data-card="secondSet"></div>
<div class="myCard" data-card="firstSet"></div>
<div class="myCard" data-card="thirdSet"></div>
<div class="myCard" data-card="secondSet"></div>
<div class="myCard" data-card="thirdSet"></div>
```

By clicking on the element you can find the event.target (your card) attribute value for the attribute data-card and:

`if(myFirstCard[data-card] == mySecondCard[data-card])`, add points, otherwise, turn the cards

```
let previousClick = null;
let nextClick = null;

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {


if(previousClick == null) previousClick = e.target[data-target]
else {
   nextClick = e.target[data-target]
   if(previousClick == nextClick) // cards with same id
}
```

}

Working code:

```
var score = 0;
var firstClick = null;
var secondoClick = null;

window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
let clicked = event.target.dataset.type;
  
if(firstClick == null){
  firstClick = clicked
} else {
  secondoClick = clicked
}

  
if(secondoClick == firstClick){
  console.log('same click')
  score++;
  firstClick = null;
  secondoClick = null;
} else if(secondoClick != null && firstClick != secondoClick) {
  console.log('metti null')
  firstClick = null;
  secondoClick = null;
}

...
```

Adapt the above code to your needs and remember that you need to change the type attribute in your HTML to data-type attribute.

Comment: so like this? 

const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");


for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
        cards[i].classList.add("open"); 
        console.log(this.id)
        
        if (myFirstCard[data-card] === mySecondCard[data-card] ) {
            console.log("hello");
        } else {
            console.log("byebye");
        }
        });
}

+ the added data-card in html?

Comment: You can actually attach the click event directly to the document object like window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {})

By doing this, each of your click will have a target (e.target) and that target will be your HTML element, or card, and it will also tell you the data attribute that you clicked and if two cards that you clicked correspond to the same data attribute.

Comment: @AnnaEllegaardSkytte edited, check the answer

Comment: I can't make it work.. I'm really new to coding 
https://codepen.io/anna100d/pen/wvgQLdW

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: I've been trying to make it work, and it does somewhat work. But not quite, i get metti null even when i click two cards that match.  https://codepen.io/anna100d/pen/wvgQLdW